# Android ksoap2 connection don't work via wifi / hotspot but with 3G/Edge

Tags: android, ksoap

I have the following problem:
I have developed an app that accesses a webservice via ksoap.
However, this connection works ONLY over the mobile network (3G/Edge).
When the phone is connected via wifi or mobile hotspot, he throws me out without loading my error.

Here is the code:

```
//Variablen
static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
static String URL = "http://wgo.*******************";
static String METHOD_NAME;
static String SOAP_ACTION;

public static String getLogins(String pubkey, String user, String ip, String password, String timeOfRequest, String timeOfLastRequest, String lastXML) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    METHOD_NAME = "GetLogins";
    SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetLogins";

    //Request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("pubkey", pubkey);
    request.addProperty("user", user);
    request.addProperty("ip", ip);
    request.addProperty("password", password);
    request.addProperty("timeOfRequest", timeOfRequest);
    request.addProperty("timeOfLastRequest", timeOfLastRequest);
    request.addProperty("lastXML", lastXML);

    //Envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;  
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    //Fehler auschließen
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

    //Ausführen
    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);
    http.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope, null);

    //Ergebnis
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
    String ergebnis = response.toString();

    return ergebnis;
}
```

I have tried everything ... I'm really desperate on .. I hope you still have a tip for me.
I used ksoap 3.3 and have tried also different Android devices with different versions

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

i think the link which you are calling from your code is blocked by your proxy setting of wifi just test with other wifi connection it will work if this is the case then am sure its not an error its your proxy setting related issue

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast answer. But i tested with 4-5 different wifi connections and a mobile hotspot (connect my android device to a iphone hotspot). Nothing works.